Efficient Template Searching and XML Retrieval in Smart Communications Draft Editor Integration
I'm currently integrating the Smart Communications draft editor into my application. Within my application's workflow, I require the ability to search for a template selector and then load it into the Draft Editor component provided by Smart Communications.
After conducting some research, I've discovered a method to generate a template's XML by utilizing the template selector's resource version ID and supplying sample data to the 'generate draft' endpoint. However, this approach necessitates more than five API calls, which seems inefficient.
I'm seeking advice on whether there's a more streamlined approach to search for a template and retrieve its XML without resorting to excessive API calls. Below, I've outlined my current API call flow for reference.


